# Allocating space for Ubuntu in dual boot installation - what are "files" and "ubuntu"?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I'm doing a full reinstall of my computer. I'm going to use Ubuntu as my main OS, and Win 10 for games that I cant get to work on Ubuntu.

I've already gotten through the Win install and I'm working on installing Ubuntu alongside. I'm stuck on the slider for allocating "drive space" in the installation of Ubuntu. The slider goes between "files" and "ubuntu").

My question is: what is the purpose of the space I'm allocating?

By this I mean: will programs be installed to "files" or "ubuntu"? what differentiates "Files" from "Ubuntu"? Will I be able to access "files"?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please see this: https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: While booted from the Ubuntu live CD/USB, use the try Ubuntu option and open the app gparted. Take a screenshot of gparted showing the disk partition structure. Edit your question above and add the screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 1):

> My Question is : what is the purpose of the space I'm allocating?

The space you are allocating is for the installation of Ubuntu. The installation process will create one or two partitions it needs for the installation of the operating system.

> By this I mean: will programs be installed to "files" or "ubuntu"?
>   what differentiates "Files" from "Ubuntu"? Will I be able to access
>   "files" ?

I am guessing that you have created an big NTFS partition next to your Windows 10 installation to either keep your files or to install Ubuntu. Ubuntu cannot use NTFS partitions. It uses a different partition scheme that Windows cannot create. Depending on the version you are trying to install, it may also need a `swap` partition. All these will be created in the part marked as "Ubuntu" by shrinking the NTFS partition you have created. The part marked as "files" will the the shrunk NTFS partition.

Yes, you will be able to read and write to the NTFS partitions from either Windows or Ubuntu. No, Ubuntu installation will not put anything in this partition.

If you do not want an additional NTFS partition, and want to allocate the whole of the big partition you have created previously to Ubuntu. You have to boot Windows again and delete this partition and keep this place unallocated.

When you start Ubuntu installation again, it will find this unallocated space in the disk and create all the partitions it needs. It won't show you the slider then.

Hope it helps